# Windows 8.1 Render control which is not in the Frame tree

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a problem because my app render buttons which are not in the controls tree. I cannot find them by Parent property. I even wrote code to hide anything and this buttons are still there.

```
var parrent = Frame as FrameworkElement;
while (parrent != null)
{
    parrent.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    parrent = parrent.Parent as FrameworkElement;
}
```

After I use this code the buttons are still there.

[image: After this code usage]

Comment: Can you show the XAML or C# (or VB) code that creates the page and the buttons? There is no evidence that you are calling the code that you supplied for the correct objects.